# How do I replace my Homebrew based Python configuration with Conda

Tags: python, homebrew, conda, miniconda

I currently have [a rather complex Python configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54738414/656912) that has evolved over the years, and I'd like to clean it up and "modernize" it.

The existing configuration has a the default macOS Python, and Homebrew's Python 3 and Python 2 all existing side-by-side, along with their associated Pips. I also have some python command line tools that these Pythons or their associated installed packages have created, and which I use more or less frequently.

What I'd like to do is:

- Leave macOS Python untouched
- Eliminate all Homebrew Python's
- Remove non-macOS Python 2 entirely
- Switch to Conda Python as my Python 3
- Have access to `mkvirtualenv` (as an alternative to creating environments) with `virtualenvwrapper`
- Have access to Jupyter

I'm not sure how to do this without creating problems, and want to confirm that the obvious thing is the safe thing:

1. use Homebrew to uninstall its Pythons,
2. install Conada, and then
3. use (Conda's) `pip` to install `mkvirtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper`, and Jupyter (and any other tools I subsequently need)

Is that the correct procedure? Is so are there particular forms of the commands I should use or options I should chose for them?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest and/or first issue is how to not break existing functionality that relies on Python.  There are two broad camps here:

1) tools and other scripts that hard-code the Python executable's location, and

2) tools and other scripts that rely on the/a system PATH variable.

#1 is the easier one.  If you aren't going to remove any Python versions, then these are no work at all...these will keep working.  If you do want to uninstall some Python versions, then you have to work to switch any tools relying on those versions you want to remove to another version that also works for that tool.  The path in question is commonly in a shebang ('#! xxx') line at the top of each main Python binary, but there are other ways that the path to the Python binary can be formed.  In short, why uninstall anything? Disk space is cheap.  Maybe instead just make sure that these unwanted versions are not referenced by any PATH variables.

#2 is the hard one.  It isn't necessarily the case that all of the tools in this category are using the version of Python you get when you just type "python" at a command prompt for your primary account.  There can be other modes of operation that initialize the execution environment (the PATH variable) in different ways, and so may be running different Python versions despite depending on the value of PATH.

Part of #2 is worrying about not just "python" references, but "python2", "python3", and possibly other variants as well.

Only once you've got a plan for dealing with the above so you don't break things can you worry about possibly getting rid of Python versions and installing new ones.  Hopefully, Brew does a good job of uninstalling the versions it's installed, so if you can remove dependencies on one or more of them, they can potentially be easily removed.  If you've got self-installed Python versions, those should be easy to uninstall as well by just removing references to them in PATH variables (or not...shouldn't be a big problem if you miss some) and then deleting the install directory.

Then there's adding the new version(s) of Python.  This can only affect #2 above.  You have to think about that one and know what affect you're going to have if the new install(s) manipulate any PATH variables.  If it only manipulates your own user's PATH, or it leaves it to you to do so, this is a much easier to understand task, but any change to the environment is a chance to break existing functionality.

Finally, there's the mechanisms for choosing different Python versions for new development, including the use of virtual envs.  This is probably the easiest part, as you can do research, try things, and test that you can do whatever you want to do.  This part of the problem is the best bounded.

I don't know anything about Jupyter, other than knowing vaguely what it is, so I don't know how that complicates all this.

UPDATE: A final note.  As you may already know, Python does a good job of isolating itself in terms of each version keeping its unique identity.  If you use the right 'pip' and 'easy_install' that are sitting right next to the 'python' binary you're going to run with, you should be cleanly affecting just that one environment.  I can't know that it's this easy for all Python versions, but I've never seen this convention broken by a version of Python that I've used.  The complications here, of course, involve which versions of these tools you're getting in various situations when they are found via a PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

First, install anaconda or miniconda. The installation is non-destructive and does not conflict with your other Python installations. Check that it works before you consider removing homebrew installed Pythons.

The `conda` command is used both as a package manager and as an environment manager. You cannot avoid creating conda environments: the default installation is already part of an environment named `base`. I'm not sure why you would want to, either.

You can use `pip` to install any package you choose into a conda environment, but since you can use `conda install` for any package available on any conda channel (e.g. 'defaults', 'conda-forge'), using `pip` often is redundant.

You could use non-conda virtual environments, but again: why? `conda create -n foo python=x.x jupyter #etc` and then `conda activate foo` is all you need to get one up and running.

Comment: I like using `virtualenvwrapper` because I have kewl customized command prompts when I'm in a virtual environment.

Comment: @orome, then `conda` will not yuck your yum. Enjoy!